# AWS S3 redirect rules with multiple conditions in JSON won't save

Tags: json, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, redirect

I am unable to get S3 to accept multiple conditions in a JSON file, as it will save only the first condition. So I can do a redirect of a single object using the following code:

```
[
{
    "Condition": {
        "KeyPrefixEquals": "myfolder"
    },
    "Redirect": {
        "HostName": "mynewdomain.com",
        "HttpRedirectCode": "301",
        "Protocol": "https",
        "ReplaceKeyPrefixWith": "mynewfolder"
    }
}
]
```

but when I try multiple conditions as below, it saves the file as in the above example, with only a single condition and shows no errors. I've got multiple files that need to be redirected to different websites, so need multiple conditions to be added to the JSON file.

```
[
    {
        "Condition": {
            "KeyPrefixEquals": "myfolder"
        },
        "Redirect": {
            "HostName": "mynewdomain.com",
            "HttpRedirectCode": "301",
            "Protocol": "https",
            "ReplaceKeyPrefixWith": "mynewfolder"
        },
       "Condition": {
            "KeyPrefixEquals": "myotherfolder"
        },
        "Redirect": {
            "HostName": "mynewdomain.com",
            "HttpRedirectCode": "301",
            "Protocol": "https",
            "ReplaceKeyPrefixWith": "mynewotherfolder"
        }
    }
]
```

Any ideas? The old way of doing this without JSON was simple. A shame there's no convertor to take the old rules and make then JSON compatible.

Answer (score 1):

Syntax is invalid since two keys with the same name exist in the same object, thus it will take only the first one. You have to make two objects, two `RoutingRule`.

```
[
    {
        "Condition": {
            "KeyPrefixEquals": "folderOne/"
        },
        "Redirect": {
            "HostName": "mydomain.com",
            "HttpRedirectCode": "301",
            "Protocol": "https",
            "ReplaceKeyPrefixWith": "folder1/"
        }
    },
    {
        "Condition": {
            "KeyPrefixEquals": "folderTwo/"
        },
        "Redirect": {
            "HostName": "mydomain.com",
            "HttpRedirectCode": "301",
            "Protocol": "https",
            "ReplaceKeyPrefixWith": "folder2/"
        }
    }
]
```

Comment: The redirection works for both conditions but only the last condition is visible in the redirection rules.

Comment: Rechecked with multiple conditions, it just ignores all of the conditions except the last one.

Comment: Have you changed your syntax to mine and still not working?

Comment: I have copied your example, replacing my domain names and folder locations and it still only keeps the last condition.

Comment: @JasSingh I have tried the above example and it worked. Have you forget putting `/` after prefix's name? Another note that it might take some time to take effect, you may want to give it 5 minutes.

Comment: Added },{ between the conditions and it works fine. Added 7 conditions, all accepted this way. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.